# Displaying code chunks in a frame in hugo using blogdown

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I have recently created a blog post using blogdown and hugo. I was able to add code folding but the code appears like regular text on the website. I am trying to display the code in a frame or something distinguishing it from the rest of the text ex:

[image]

I have tried everything but could not figure how to do it. I am guessing it has to deal something with the theme I am using. I am using Hugo Nuo.

You can find the current shape of the blog post here:
https://www.staturk.xyz/post/poll-accuracy-in-turkish-elections/

Here is the beginning of my .rmd file for the post where I am trying to display the code in a frame:

````
---
title: "Poll Accuracy in Turkish Elections"
date: '2018-12-25'
slug: poll-accuracy-in-turkish-elections
tags:
- Polls
- Politics
- R
categories:
- Turkish Politics
- Rstats
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
 htmltools::includeHTML("~/Documents/Personal/Projects/Blog/Turkstat/content/media/posts/header.html")
```

```{r echo = F, results='hide', message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(scales)
library(knitr)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps here - figuring out what to style and then adding the style to the theme.

### Figuring out what to style

Looking at the raw html for the post (`ctrl-U` in Chrome), the code fragments are wrapped in a `<pre class="r"><code>..</code></pre>` tag set. So, we could give it a border (for instance) by adding the following to the html header :

```
<style>
  pre.r { 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 2px; 
  }
</style>
```

### Adding to the theme

Looking at the theme code, the best way to accomplish this seems to be to override the head partial in `themes/{theme_name}/layouts/partials/head.html`. Copy that file up into the the same area of the site folder. The following commands will do the trick if you are on linux:

```
cd $sitedir
mkdir -p layouts/partials
cp themes/hugo-nuo/layouts/partial/head.html layouts/partial
```

Then edit the copy of the file to add the above style fragment.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine! Thank you for the help! Just one comment, the css tag needs to be ```pre.r``` and not ```pre.r code``` otherwise every single line of code gets the styling rather than the chunk (in case if you want to add that as an edit for other people checking out this question).

Comment: Ah ... good point - you want to style the container. Yes, I'll fix that.